# Selecting arbitrary value as max

Tags: sql, oracle, max, rank

I have two tables, STUDENTS and LOG.

The LOG table may have 0 or more records in it per student. The records in the LOG table are categorized by column SUBTYPE. Values for SUBTYPE are: 'H', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'M', 'P1', 'P2', and 'Px'.

I am trying to produce a report that will list each student name one time, and the *most severe* of the codes in the LOG table.

I naturally think of MAX(subtype), but that won't work because I'm not trying to select the actual maximum alphanumeric value of the subtypes - I'm trying to select based on a pre-defined "SEVERITY". Severity, BTW, is not stored in the DB, so I need to define this somehow inside of the query.

For Example...

```
STUDENTS TABLE
ID       LAST_NAME       FIRST_NAME
------------------------------------
2        Smith           John
3        Jones           Bob
4        Bower           Jack


LOG TABLE
ID      STUDENTSID       SUBTYPE
------------------------------------
1       2                 P1
2       2                  M
3       2                 L1
4       3                 L2
5       3                 P2
6       3                  H
```

The subtype values should actually be ranked/sorted as:

```
(From Least Severe)
1. P1
2. L1
3.  M
4. L2
5. P2
6.  H
7. L3
8. Px
(To Most Severe)
```

Below is what I need my report to look like. Note, Jack Bower is not on the report, as he does not have any records in the log table.

```
DESIRED REPORT OUTPUT:
John Smith --- M
Bob Jones ---- H
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
order by
  case subtype
    when 'P1' then 1
    when 'L1' then 2
    when 'M'  then 3
    ...
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prioritize the subtypes accordingly using `row_number` function. Then select the first row for each student.

```
select id,first_name,last_name 
from (
select s.*
,row_number() over(partition by s.id 
                   order by case when l.subtype='P1' then 1
                                 when l.subtype='L1' then 2
                                 when l.subtype='M' then 3
                                 when l.subtype='L2' then 4
                                 when l.subtype='P2' then 5
                                 when l.subtype='H' then 6
                                 when l.subtype='L3' then 7
                                 when l.subtype='Px' then 8
                   end desc) as rnum
from students s
join logs l on s.id=l.studentsid
) x
where rnum = 1
```

Comment: @mathguy .. ordering returns all records ordered. this returns 1 row per student which is what the op needs. fyi..i am not a fan of posting duplicate answers and i only posted this because the other answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Right, I was coming to that conclusion myself.